# Drupal 8 - How to logout the user after webform submission

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-webform

I'm trying to logout a user after they submitted a webform.

I tried redirecting the user to my logout link '/user/logout' by using the webform settings under confirmation.

The confirmation type of my webform is a URL (redirects to a custom path or URL).

I've set that custom path to '/user/logout', but it just refreshes the page. Even though, the submit was succesfull.

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding a custom submission with a RedirectResponse.

custom submission example:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223342/add-a-custom-submission-handler-to-a-form

redirect example:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2023537